# Cannot split with " \ " in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to split my data using `.split('\')`, but its not working an error occurs "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token".

can we split with '\'?

Comment: add what you tried in OP

Comment: try adding one more slash before it e.g. \\

Comment: Satya.. thanks it worked

Comment: I'm sure it's a duplicate but I didn't find a relevant QA. I'll be happy to close the question if somebody finds it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just split on a String here because you need to escape the `\` (String -> double quotes).

So `.split("\\"`) it is.

Answer (score 1):

In a literal string, a `\` must be escaped.

See all escapes: [Escape notation in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation)

Answer (score 1):

Use below syntax for escape the slash :

```
var str = "your string";
str  = str.split("\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with escaping this slash as follow

```
var str = "your\requirement";    
str.split("\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is one character that needs to be escaped when using a string literal.

Try calling `.split('\\')` on your string.