# Unable to split converted mimetype in javascript

Tags: node.js, split, rename

I am using the following code to rename a file that has been uploaded to my node.js server.  I get the 'mimetype' of the uploaded file and convert it to a string, whereby my goal is to 'split' that string at the backslash ('/').  I should then be able to use the 'extension' (i.e. the 'jpg' or 'gif' or 'png' or whatever) to create a new file name.  My problem is I keep getting an 'Unexpected token' error when I do the 'split'...I have confirmed the mimetype has been converted to a string...therefore I cannot to save my life understand why the 'split' does not work...?  Code is as follows:

```
  //A means of ensuring only images are uploaded.
  //'files' is an array of uploaded image files, omitted for clarity

   var len = files.length;
   var i;

   for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    if (files[i] != "undefined") {

    const host = req.hostname;
    const filePath = req.protocol + "://" + host + '/' + files[i].path;
    const image = files[i].mimetype.startsWith('image/');
    const type = files[i].mimetype.toString();  //convert mimetype to string

     if(image) {
     console.log('photo #' + i + ' uploaded');
     console.log('uploaded file: ' + files[i].filename + ' saved within: ' + files[i].destination + ' at path: ' + files[i].path);

     console.log('photo #' + i + ' filepath: ' + filePath);
     console.log('photo #' + i + ' image extension is: ' + type);  //returns 'image/jpg'
     console.log('photo #' + i + ' TYPEOF is: ' + typeof type);  //returns 'string'
     var extends = type.split("/");  //"split" on "backslash"  'UNEXPECTED TOKEN' ERROR HERE!!! 
     var targetPath = filePath + "." + extends[1]  //'extends[1]' should be jpg or png or whatever

     console.log('RENAMED target path for photo #' + i + ' is: ' + targetPath);

      fs.rename(filePath, targetPath, function(err) {
       if (err) {
        console.log("Unable to rename photo #" + i + " file...!")
       } else {
        console.log("Successfully renamed the file!")
       }
      }) 

     } else {
     console.log("file # " + i + " received--however wrong format");
     }

    }  //if NOT 'undefined'

   }  //for loop
```

I thank you in advance for any suggestions...this is driving me crazy...

Comment: Reference: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277783/cannot-split-with-in-js?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I tried 'var extends = type.split("//");' however still getting an "Unexpected token extends" error...  This is ridiculous.

Comment: Is there a way I can work-around by stripping the last 3 characters of the 'type' string...that should give me what I seek, which is simply the extension following the '/'...or perhaps the entire string following the '/'...?

Answer (score 0):

I have an example with javascript (I can't reply in your answer )
[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I figured the problem seems to be with the variable name...'extends'.  I changed it and now it seems to perform the split without difficulty...and I did not have to escape the backslash either ("/").  Thank you for your replies.

Comment: I do not know what the cause of the error was...I can only think perhaps the word 'extends' is some sort of internal reserved word...?

Comment: I think it is not the causes. Maybe we wrong somewhere, or value "extends" not exist ( after split text to array)

Comment: If not that then I have no explanation as to the cause of the problem